# Unable to Connect AWS RDS from SQL Developer

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds, amazon-ebs

I just need help here,
I'm just getting started into AWS RDS, I have web application and I have deployed into AWS Through  AWS EBS
and now I wanted to connect my DB, for that I attached RDS to my application in beanstalk. When testing the connection, I am Getting this error

[image]

This is my ENDPOINT:

[image]

Here are my RDS DB Configuration:

[image]

and SID is:

[image]

please help me sort this, I got stuck here from 2 days.
Thank You.... :)

Answer (score 2):

Please, in your connection setup in SQL Developer, in the **Hostname** field, just remove the literal `:3306` at the end of your hostname string: this value is in fact the port in which the database is listening.

In order to complete your connection setup, enter the value `3306` in the **Port** field instead of the `1521` you indicated in your image.